# Read format specifiers from text file

Tags: c, io, formatting, printf, string-formatting

Is there a way to read a format specifier, such as `%s` or `%d` from a text file and then use this specifier in a string variable for a `printf` later on?

For example, if I had a file that contains

```
foo=%s
```

would i be able to do something like this?

```
FILE * f = fopen("/home/foo/bar", "r");

charn * s_buf = malloc(sizeof(charn) * 256);
fgets(s_buf, 255, f);
  
printf(s_buf, "bar");
```

and get this printed as a result:

```
foo=bar
```

I know it obviously doesn't work exactly like this, but i hope you understand what I'm going for and maybe know of a way to do something like this

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write a specific char in your file that indicates data type and then switch case with corresponding printf ?

Comment: It works a lot like that. The format string is nothing special: just a string. You can specify it as a constant or read it into a variable from a file or build it however you like. Security issues abound when reading it from external sources, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct but you have to think about what will happen if the file contains a %d instead of a %s, or any other invalid format specifier for what has to be displayed.

It is correct to malloc() space for s_buf but a static array will do as well. You won't need to call free(s_buf) later.

Comment: thank you, it works now. the problem was actually that i copied the file from windows to linux without converting the encoding.
I copied the code from my project and modified a bit, that's why the malloc is there. I need a dynamic length.
I can control what's in the text file, I just needed kind of a placeholder to insert variables from my code